# Sqlite couldn't show the correct current time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I have set my time as US Locale.I have made database in Sqlite.In database i have fields like Entry_Date which set as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP..Now i run query like

```
   SELECT time('now')

o/p:  06:22:09
```

It display wrong time.so my question is How do i set the Sqlite time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `localtime` modifier to the `time` function.

```
sqlite> select time('now','localtime');
06:38:51
```

See [Date and Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

**Update:** For the record, here's how to output a unix epoch date:

```
sqlite> select time(1316638370,'unixepoch','localtime');
06:52:50
```

Comment: but when i insert any record it will take date as currentdate with default time as 06:22:09.then how do i set that time?I set Entry_date as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @Sheweta depends on your data-type. dates can be stored as text, real or int. You're better of using real or int to store unix time-stamps for various reasons, One being that they are timezone independent.